# how to get client information once order accepted in whmcs and send data to veeam to create account automation

Tags: whmcs, veeam

Good day, Im new to WHMCS and Veeam, I would like to automate the process of when a client buys something, and the order is accepted it should automatically send the client information to VEEAM console and create an account .

does anyone have ideas about how I can implement this using hooks and VEEAM API at restful

Comment: You must write a Product Module, and implement the method `CreateAccount`; See: https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/houssam11350/8e9fa9c3a41130dd445b91fed643a41b

Comment: thank you for your responds, busy reading up